# Error displaying Facebook user data in React native

Tags: react-native

I tried to find a solution but still can't find it. I followed the latest EXPO docs on Facebook in react native login using the line of code below. Everything is fine until I can't show the username?

```
 logIn = async () => {
    try {
      await Facebook.initializeAsync({
        appId: '468444667537113',
      });
      const {
        type,
        token,

      } = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync({
        permissions: ['public_profile'],
      });
      if (type === 'success') {

        const response = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${token}`);
        alert('Logged in!', `Hi ${(await response.json()).name}!`); //Show only "Logged in", but no username //
        console.log(response.json().name);   <--- error here (undefined)
      } else {
        // type === 'cancel'
      }
    } catch ({ message }) {
      alert(`Facebook Login Error: ${message}`);
    }
  };
```

By the way, how can I get my profile picture on Facebook?